# Missing ODBCConfig for SQLite and LibreOffice Base

Tags: libreoffice, database, sqlite

I have used OpenOffice Base as a front end for SQlite databases, in 10.04 linked via ODBC.

I am updating to 12.04, so I loaded LibreOffice Base, looks just like OObase. I have 12.04 on one drive and 10.04 on another.

I loaded Sqliteman, sqlite3, unixodbc-bin, unixodbc, libsqliteodbc, sqlitebrowser.

I copied my databases directory over.

But in terminal ODBCConfig is not on the 12.04 system.

So I copied `odbc.ini` from the home directory on 10.04 to 12.04 home directory, and now LibreOffice Base can access my database, and all is fine.

Anyone know what is the problem with ODBCConfig, is it another victim of the change in QT? Of course I could edit `odbc.ini` with jedit, now I can see the format.

In terminal I tried `sudo find / -name ODBCConfig`, but its not there.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to install the package `unixodbc-bin` then run the command `ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4`.